# Trying to create a GROUP BY with eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
$collections = Collection::selectRaw("DATE(created_at) as collection_date, sum(gross_amount) as amount")
    ->groupBy('collection_date')
    ->paginate(10);
```

When I do that it displays that collection_date does not exist in the table, so I wonder how can I create a group by with just DATE() in eloquent?

Thanks

Comment: Probably need to do `groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))`; `collection_date` as an "as ... " alias isn't available at that point in the query.

Comment: Are you using MySQL?

Comment: You can do that with raw query `->groupBy(DB::raw('collection_date')`

Answer (score 0):

Based on Laravel docs, pagination doesn't work with the groupBy clause properly.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results

> Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database and create a paginator manually.